# Optimizing method in Java

Tags: java, oop

I want to add two enemies to the pane, `Dragon` and `Orc`. Both of these classes extend a super class called `Entity`, and I want to create a single method for both these methods. I have tried using `List<? extends Sprite> list` and `List<? super Sprite> list`, but it didn't work as I need to both add the object to a list and read it later on when calling the add method.

```
public void addDragon(List<Dragon> list) {
    double imageWidth = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Dragon dragon = new Dragon();
        imageWidth = dragon.getWidth();
        pane.getChildren().add(dragon);
        list.add(dragon);
    }
}

public void addDragon(List<Orc> list) {
    double imageWidth = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Orc orc = new Orc();
        imageWidth = orc.getWidth();
        pane.getChildren().add(orc);
        list.add(orc);
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I have tried using "List list" and "List list" [...]*" - I do not comprehend. A remark: instead of `List<Dragon>` and `List<Orc>`, you should use `List<? super Dragon>` and `List<? super Orc>`, applying the [PECS mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: You could use an Interface.

Comment: Can you elaborate, Compass? :)

Comment: FYI, optimization generally refers to performance tuning. Merging redundant code is not an optimization in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

Pass in a `Supplier` of the type you want to create:

```
public <T extends Sprite> void addThings(List<? super T> list, Supplier<T> supplier) {
```

And then replace the constructor with an invocation of that supplier:

```
T thing = supplier.get();
imageWidth = thing.getWidth();
pane.getChildren().add(thing);
list.add(thing);
```

You would invoke this something like:

```
addThings(listOfDragons, Dragon::new);
addThings(listOfOrcs, Orc::new);
```

Comment: I think the common supertype is `Sprite`. But technically the upper bound isn't necessary at all.

Comment: @shmosel not even to invoke the width method (don't know why that's done, though...)

Comment: No, it probably is necessary. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @shmosel well, I've updated it to use `Sprite`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your class Structure is like this

```
public interface Entity {
// abstract methods here
}

public class Orc implements Entity {
 //Code here
}


public class Dragon implements Entity {
 //Code here
}
```

now modify your method as below

```
    public <T extends Entity> void addDragon(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz) 
  throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    double imageWidth = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        T enemy = clazz.newInstance();
        imageWidth = enemy.getWidth();
        pane.getChildren().add(enemy);
        list.add(enemy);
    }
   }
```

Here **< T extends Entity >** makes your method flexible to be called by passing any class which are implementing Enemies.

Comment: This only works iff. `T` has ha parameterless, accessible constructor.

Comment: In which class do i place that particular method? Is public <T extends entity> a new class?

Comment: @Yani no, it is a generic method. But from its declaration, the [solution of Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162318/4216641) (using `List<? super T> list` as parameter) is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Generic might help you

```
public <T extends Entity> void addEntity(List<T> list, Class<T> clazz) {
  double imageWidth = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    T entity = clazz.newInstance();
    imageWidth = entity.getWidth();
    pane.getChildren().add(entity);
    list.add(entity);
  }
}
```

Comment: This only works iff. `T` has ha parameterless, accessible constructor.

Comment: @Turing85 it doesn't, because it will throw a checked exception.

Comment: @AndyTurner and it is set `deprecated` =)

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface, or add methods to Entity, for the things you need to do to all entities.  This would include a factory method to create a new instance of the specific subtype, and getWidth.   Call addEnemy with a prototype instance of the type to be added.

```
public void addEnemy(List<Entity> list,Entity enemy) {
double imageWidth = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Entity someEnemy = enemy.createNewInstance();
    imageWidth = someEnemy .getWidth();
    pane.getChildren().add(someEnemy );
    list.add(someEnemy );
}
```

}